# In Rollup, create ESM module with no babel transpiling except Flow

Tags: javascript, babeljs, flowtype, es6-modules, rollup

I'm trying to release a library that contains Flow syntax in several forms, using Rollup and Babel:

- UMD, ES5 (works)
- UMD, ES5, minified (works)
- ES module (problem)

Specifically, I want the ES module version to be as minimally transpiled as possible: it should use the full range of ES6 features just as I wrote them. I can't seem to stop Babel transpiling down to ES5 though - it creates an `_objectSpread2()` function and replaces every spread operator with it.

The only reason I want to use Babel is for the Flow syntax. Specifically, converting class property syntax:

```
class Foo { 
  myProp = 1;
}
```

(The standalone tool `flow-remove-types` does not transform class syntax, so its output is not valid JS).

[This](https://github.com/stevage/map-gl-utils/blob/master/rollup-esm.config.js) is the Rollup config that currently over-transpiles, to ES5:

```
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import flow from 'rollup-plugin-flow';
export default [
    {
        input: 'src/index.js',
        output: [
            {
                file: 'dist/index.esm.js',
                format: 'esm', // ES2015 modules version so consumers can tree-shake
            },
        ],
        plugins: [flow(), commonjs(), nodeResolve()],
    },
];
```

Even when I remove the presets, it still does exactly the same thing:

```
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
export default [
    {
        input: 'src/index.js',
        output: [
            {
                file: 'dist/index.esm.js',
                format: 'esm', // ES2015 modules version so consumers can tree-shake
            },
        ],
        plugins: [
            babel({
                presets: [],
            }),
        ],
    },
];
```

Do I need to change something in .babelrc? It is currently as follows:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "esmodules": true
                }
            }
        ],
        ["@babel/preset-flow"]
    ]
}
```

The library is [here](https://github.com/stevage/map-gl-utils).

Comment: _does not transform class syntax, so its output is not valid JS_ Why is that? Classes are perfectly valid in JS

Comment: Sorry that should have read, class property syntax. Which is not standard JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I think the problem was that .babelrc was being applied even in the ESM case. So the answer is:

1. Remove the `.babelrc` file
2. Move its configuration to `rollup.config.js`
3. Configure `rollup-esm.config.js` to explicitly handle class syntax.

Rollup.config.js:

```
...
        plugins: [
            flow(),
            commonjs(),
            nodeResolve(),
            babel({
                babelHelpers: 'bundled',
                presets: [
                    [
                        '@babel/preset-env',
                        {
                            targets: {
                                esmodules: true,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                    ['@babel/preset-flow'],
                ],
            }),
        ],
```

rollup-esm.config.js:

```
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
export default [
    {
        input: 'src/index.js',
        output: [
            {
                file: 'dist/index.esm.js',
                format: 'esm', // ES2015 modules version so consumers can tree-shake
            },
        ],
        plugins: [
            babel({
                plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'],
                presets: ['@babel/preset-flow'],
            }),
        ],
    },
];
```